# Are there more ways to use .. (dotdot) in Rust aside from ranges?

Tags: rust

I found out that `..` can be used in structs in this way:

```
struct Test {
    e1: i32,
    e2: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let test = Test { e1: 1, e2: 2 };
    let Test { e1: x, .. } = test;
    let Test { e2: y, .. } = test;
    let test2 = Test { ..test };
    let test3 = Test { e1: 2, e2: 3, ..test };
}
```

Are there more ways to use `..`? Is there an overview of them somewhere?

Comment: The question in the title doesn't match the question at the bottom.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are not other usages, as you can see [in the reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/appendix-02-operators.html):

- `(.., expr.., ..expr, expr..expr)`: right-exclusive range literal.
- `(..expr)`: struct literal update syntax.
- `(variant(x, ..), struct_type { x, .. })`: “and the rest” pattern binding.

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch18-03-pattern-syntax.html#ignoring-remaining-parts-of-a-value-with- - i believe this is the last one..